# How to pass context to Picasso

Tags: android, android-viewholder

Hello I am trying to add image using Picasso,but having problems to get context for Picasso in adapter when i use following view holder :

This is my adapter

```
               public class DataAdapter extends 
                  RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
                            private ArrayList<String> 
                              al_prod_name,al_prod_price,al_prod_id,
                                 al_prod_image;

                    public DataAdapter(ArrayList<String> al_prod_id, 
                           ArrayList<String> al_prod_name,
                               ArrayList<String> al_prod_price, 
                                  ArrayList<String> al_prod_image) {
                                   this.al_prod_id = al_prod_id;
                                   this.al_prod_price = al_prod_price;
                                   this.al_prod_name = al_prod_name;
                                   this.al_prod_image = al_prod_image
                               }


                      public DataAdapter.ViewHolder 
                         onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                              View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardrow, viewGroup, 
                                    false);
                              return new ViewHolder(view);
                             }

                        public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder 
                          viewHolder, int i) {

                             viewHolder.tv_prod_name.setText
                               (al_prod_name.get(i));
                             viewHolder.tv_prod_price.setText
                               (al_prod_price.get(i));

                        Picasso.with().load(al_prod_image.get(i))
                       .placeholder(R.drawable.floatingicon)
                       .error(R.drawable.floatingicon).
                       .into(viewHolder.img_prod);

                          }
                      public int getItemCount() {
                      return al_prod_id.size();
                      }

                   public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
                      private TextView tv_prod_name,tv_prod_price;
                      private ImageView img_prod;
                      public ViewHolder(View view) {
                      super(view);

                       tv_prod_name = (TextView)view
                       .findViewById(R.id.tv_prod_name);
                        tv_prod_price = (TextView)view
                       .findViewById(R.id.tv_prod_price);
                       img_prod = (ImageView)view
                       .findViewById(R.id.img_prod);
                       }
                       }
                       }
```

Please help to get context.This is how i set Adapter:

```
                       RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new 
                       DataAdapter(al_prod_id,al_prod_name,
                       al_prod_price,al_prod_image);
```

Comment: pass activity.this in DataAdapter() constructor and use it in picasso

Comment: just use `viewHolder.tv_prod_name.getContext()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplest solution is use ***viewHolder.itemView.getContext()***

```
Picasso.with(viewHolder.itemView.getContext()).load(al_prod_image.get(i))
                   .placeholder(R.drawable.floatingicon)
                   .error(R.drawable.floatingicon).
                   .into(viewHolder.img_prod);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your constructor to

```
private Context context;
public DataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> al_prod_id, 
                       ArrayList<String> al_prod_name,
                           ArrayList<String> al_prod_price, 
                              ArrayList<String> al_prod_image) {
                               this.context = context;
                               this.al_prod_id = al_prod_id;
                               this.al_prod_price = al_prod_price;
                               this.al_prod_name = al_prod_name;
                               this.al_prod_image = al_prod_image
                           }
```

Now call your adapter as

```
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new 
                   DataAdapter(context, al_prod_id,al_prod_name,
                   al_prod_price,al_prod_image);
```

Here context is your activity reference. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Pass your activity context to DataAdapter

```
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new  DataAdapter(yourActivity.this,al_prod_id,al_prod_name,
                   al_prod_price,al_prod_image);
```

DataAdapter

```
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> al_prod_name,al_prod_price,al_prod_id,al_prod_image;

public DataAdapter(Context mContext,ArrayList<String> al_prod_id,  ArrayList<String> al_prod_name,ArrayList<String> al_prod_price, ArrayList<String> al_prod_image)
{
   this.mContext=mContext;
   this.al_prod_id = al_prod_id;
   this.al_prod_price = al_prod_price;
   this.al_prod_name = al_prod_name;
   this.al_prod_image = al_prod_image
}

//set image
  Picasso.with(mContext).load(al_prod_image.get(i))
                   .placeholder(R.drawable.floatingicon)
                   .error(R.drawable.floatingicon).
                   .into(viewHolder.img_prod);
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a data member in your adapter Context context;
Write the constructor for your adapter like this,

```
DataAdapter(Context context, otherAurguments);
```

and when creating adapter

```
DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(yourActivityName.this , otherAurguments);
```

Answer (score 1):

Every view has a context. I recommend you to use `getApplicationContext()` to prevent app crashing when activity context becomes null

```
Picasso.with(itemView.getContext()).load(al_prod_image.get(i))
```

or

```
Picasso.with(itemView.getContext().getApplicationContext()).load(al_prod_image.get(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

From Activity,

```
 RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new DataAdapter(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this, al_prod_id,al_prod_name, al_prod_price,al_prod_image);
```

In Adapter,

```
   private Context context;

public DataAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> al_prod_id, ArrayList<String> al_prod_name, ArrayList<String> al_prod_price, ArrayList<String> al_prod_image) {
     this.context= mContext;
     this.al_prod_id = al_prod_id;
     this.al_prod_price = al_prod_price;
     this.al_prod_name = al_prod_name;
     this.al_prod_image = al_prod_image
 }
```

Use this with context with Picasso

```
Picasso.with(context).load(al_prod_image.get(i))
                   .placeholder(R.drawable.floatingicon)
                   .error(R.drawable.floatingicon).
                   .into(viewHolder.img_prod);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your DataAdapter constructor like this make a Context object in your adapter class and change your constructor like this

```
 public DataAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> al_prod_id, 
                           ArrayList<String> al_prod_name,
                               ArrayList<String> al_prod_price, 
                                  ArrayList<String> al_prod_image) {
                                   this.al_prod_id = al_prod_id;
                                   this.al_prod_price = al_prod_price;
                                   this.al_prod_name = al_prod_name;
                                   this.al_prod_image = al_prod_image;
this.mContext = context;
                               }
```